# Facebook Content and Ownership

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-apps

I am working on an app that imports photos from facebook. It creates a few "auto albums" for the users including one called "Photos of Me", which I think is pretty self explanitory (Yes, the "photos you're tagged in" one, provided by facebook).

Anyway, how do I deal with ownership of these photos within my app?
do I...

1. Give the user ownership of these photos (of themselves, but "owned" by other facebook users), or...
2. Create dummy accounts for the real owners in case they ever use my application?

Thanks

PS - it is also possible to do both, the app already supports multiple owners of a photo

**update**: I am aware that facebook provides this functionality already, That is how I'm getting the content to begin with :)

Also, we're **only storing IDs**, the question is whether it's a good idea to associate the photos (by id) with more than one owner on our site

The site is associating the photos because it allows users to do various actions with them, like aggregation (from lots of networks), creating a single rss feed, linking to a digital picture frame, etc. I just didn't think that was relevant to the question :/

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the facebook developer wiki, you're not allowed to store facebook user data for more than 24 hours unless you've specifically prompted the user for extended permissions.  So you shouldn't be storing the photos themselves.  You can store the photo ID's, but you probably wouldn't be asking this question if you were just storing ID's.

You may be able to get around that by specifically asking the user to import the photos into your application, but I don't see how this would be better than prompting for extended permissions, and you would be in a legal gray area.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Storable_Information

Comment: If just storing IDs, why not just link them to their photos if/when they join your site?

Comment: We actually do ask for extended permissions for other reasons an over 95% of our users grant them - that's not really the point though. The real issue I have is who should own a photo in my application? the person who is importing it (because it's a photo of THEM) or the person who it belongs to on facebook?

Comment: The only problem with doing just option #1 above is that the original uploader of the photo is forced to either allow the photo in your app, or delete the photo completely from facebook.   When a new user signs up, you could scan your own database for any of their photos that are already posted and give them hide/remove privileges.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality already exsits within Facebook, as an album that I believe is called "Tagged Photos."  Also, your question makes it sound like it either stores them off-Facebook or off-line on the user's computer.  This is another grey area, since any photos the user is in the user didn't take, and likely doesn't have the copyright.

Comment: Yeah... there's a link that says "View Photos of Me" right under your profile picture.

Comment: That isn't the point of the application - I'm just giving an example of a set of photos that would come into my app where the user (of my app) would not be the facebook user who owns the photos